# Powerquery-appending files giving error

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I am trying to append close to 10000 excel files (each having size of 50-100 kb). Half the way into the process I am running into an error with the PQ. The error hits half the way when I am appending files and it is impossible to figure out which .xlsx file is the one causing the issue.

[image: Error seen in PQ]

PQ's Queries and Connections pane shows the following error at the same time:

[image: This is what is seen in the Queries and Connection pane]

How do I go about resolving this issue other than going one by one manually and uploading query on PQ until I find the file(s) which are giving me the errors? Thanks for reading!

Comment: Could always use divide and conquer. Split by halves each time, check one half if runs ok discard. Take other half and split in half and test one half etc......Though not ideal if multiple files causing the problem. Possibility a file somehow locked?

Comment: Are you running on 64 bit with sufficient ethernet connection?

Comment: Yes it is a 64 bit office 16 with sufficient ethernet connection...thanks for the reply....yes it is more of Manual process it seems :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've frequently run into issues where PQ outright fails when it runs into "error" cells in excel workbooks, even if you've tried to remove errors in earlier steps. I'm not clear on the criteria that causes this, but I wonder if that could be the case here since it mentions a "#VALUE!" error in that message? While PQ should probably be handling this more gracefully, I made a couple of queries that let me input a directory and it will return the workbook, sheet, and row of every cell error in every excel file in that directory. I've never tried it with 10k excel files, but if my code were cleaned up to be more efficient it would probably work quickly enough.

The query that gets all the raw excel file data looks like this:

```
let
    Source = Folder.Files(YOUR DIRECTORY HERE),
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each not Text.StartsWith([Name], "~")),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows1", each Text.EndsWith([Extension], ".xlsx") or Text.EndsWith([Extension], ".xlsm")),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "WorkbookData", each Excel.Workbook([Content])),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Folder Path", "Name", "WorkbookData"}),
    #"Expanded WorkbookData" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "WorkbookData", {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Name"}, {"WorkbookData.Data", "WorkbookData.Hidden", "WorkbookData.Item", "WorkbookData.Kind", "WorkbookData.Name"}),
    #"Filtered Rows2" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded WorkbookData", each ([WorkbookData.Kind] = "Sheet")),
    #"Removed Other Columns1" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows2",{"Folder Path", "Name", "WorkbookData.Name", "WorkbookData.Data"}),
    ExpandedData = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns1", "WorkbookData.Data", Table.ColumnNames(Table.Combine(#"Removed Other Columns1"[WorkbookData.Data]))),
    IdentifySheets = Table.AddColumn(ExpandedData, "UniqueSheet", each [Folder Path]&[Name]&[WorkbookData.Name]),
    SheetRowCounts = Table.Group(IdentifySheets, {"UniqueSheet"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), type number}}),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(SheetRowCounts, "PerSheetRow", each List.Numbers(1, [Count], 1)),
    #"Expanded PerSheetIndex" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom2", "PerSheetRow"),
    IndexBase = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Expanded PerSheetIndex", "Index", 0, 1),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(IdentifySheets, "Index", 0, 1),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Index",{"Index"},IndexBase,{"Index"},"NewColumn",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded NewColumn" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "NewColumn", {"PerSheetRow"}, {"PerSheetRow"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded NewColumn",{"UniqueSheet", "Index"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Removed Columns", List.Combine({{"Folder Path", "Name", "WorkbookData.Name", "PerSheetRow"}, List.RemoveMatchingItems(Table.ColumnNames(ExpandedData), {"Folder Path", "Name", "WorkbookData.Name"})}))
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```

And that part is setup as connection only query, since I don't want to load the data of every sheet of every workbook I'm checking.

The query I use to load the rows with errors in it looks like this:

```
let
Source = NAME OF THE QUERY ABOVE,
    #"Kept Errors" = Table.SelectRowsWithErrors(Source, Table.ColumnNames(Source)),
    ColumnList = Table.FromList(Table.ColumnNames(#"Kept Errors")),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(ColumnList, "Custom", each "ERROR"),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Replacements", each Record.FieldValues(_)),
    ErrorReplacements = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Replacements"}),
    #"Replaced Errors" = Table.ReplaceErrorValues(#"Kept Errors", ErrorReplacements[Replacements]),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Replaced Errors",{{"PerSheetRow", "SheetRow"}, {"Name", "Workbook"}, {"WorkbookData.Name", "Sheet"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

I couldn't find a way to get PQ convert the "error" cells to a string of which specific error it is (probably possible, I just don't know how), so instead I just have it replace all the error cells with "ERROR" and have conditional formatting on my sheet to highlight that.

Can't say how functional this would be for your case, but it has helped me numerous times to find errors cells in sets of excel files though.